# JavaFX NullPointerException Button in other class

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception

I've to create an application for a school project. After you login, you should go to the dashboard. That works, but, it throws a NullPointerException when I try to set the button do disabled.

In this file, the stage is changing (after logging in):

```
public class ScreenController {
    public void setScene(Stage stage, Parent root,Button button, String file){
        if(file == "dashboard"){
            stage = (Stage) button.getScene().getWindow();
            try {
                root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Dashboard.fxml"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IOException: "+ex);
            }
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setTitle("Corendon - Dashboard");
            stage.setScene(scene);

            stage.show();
            Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
        }
    }
}
```

And on the last line, the button should be set to disabled...

```
Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
```

... by this class:

```
public class Dashboard extends ScreenController {
    @FXML public Button buttonDashboard1;

    public Dashboard(){
        buttonDashboard1.setDisable(true);
    }
}
```

But that is not working it throws the NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at 
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fastenyourseatbelts.Dashboard.<init>(Dashboard.java:11)
    at fastenyourseatbelts.ScreenController.setScene(ScreenController.java:33)
    at fastenyourseatbelts.LoginController.buttonLogin(LoginController.java:74)
    ... 59 more
```

I'm trying for hours now, but I don't get the solution... Does anyone know what is going wrong and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code from the constructor of your controller to the `initialize`. This method is invoked by the `FXMLLoader`, after injection of all fields is completed and therefore should have access to the `buttonDashboard1` instance:

```
public class Dashboard extends ScreenController {
    @FXML public Button buttonDashboard1;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        buttonDashboard1.setDisable(true);
    }
}
```

You also have to make sure the controller is either specified in the root element of the fxml file e.g. (replace `packagename` with the package of the `Dashboard` class)

```xml
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packagename.Dashboard">
    <children>
        <Button text="click me" fx:id="buttonDashboard1"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

or set as controller for the fxml before loading it:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Dashboard.fxml"));
Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
loader.setController(dashboard);
root = loader.load();
```

(don't use a `fx:controller` attribute in this case)

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! Thanks for your help, fabian! I can continue the project :)